# "NO" mostrar el resultado de datos de envio de PHPMAILER

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual hago una inserción a la base de datos de un formulario, envió los datos mediante AJAX, si la inserción a la base de datos es correcta hago el envió de un correo con los datos que ha puesto el usuario mas las imágenes, todo funciona de lujo, el tema viene que cuando se envía el correo me muestra una serie de datos que no quiero que se vean, solo quiero que se muestre el mensaje en **VERDE de Registro Exitoso** y no los datos del PHPmailer.

Este es el Script con el que envio los datos y traigo los resultados

```
<script>
$("#formulario").submit(function(event) {

    var parametros = $(this).serialize();
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formulario"));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/insertar.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(objeto) {
            $("#modalMensaje").modal('show');
            $("#mensaje").html('Enviando Datos......');
        },
        success: function(datos) {
            $("#modalMensaje").modal('show');
            $("#mensaje").html(datos);
            

        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Este es el código donde hago la inserción a la BD y mando el correo en dado si se hizo bien la inserción.

```
    <?php
require_once('../db.php');
require_once('../conexion.php');
require_once('correos.php');

$patrocinador = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["patrocinador"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE curp = '" . $patrocinador . "'");
$rw = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$id_patrocinador = $rw['id'];

$id_newsocio = intval($_POST["id_newsocio"]);
$name = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["name"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$a_p = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["a_p"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$a_m = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["a_m"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$curp = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["curp"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$telefono = intval($_POST["telefono"]);
$correo = strtolower(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["correo"], ENT_QUOTES))));
$date_added = date("Y-m-d");

$imagen = $_FILES['imagen']["name"];


$resultado = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO amigos (id,patrocinador,name,a_p,a_m,curp,telefono,correo,date_added) VALUES
('" . $id_newsocio . "','" . $id_patrocinador . "', '" . $name . "','" . $a_p . "','" . $a_m . "','" . $curp . "','" . $telefono . "','" . $correo . "', '" . $date_added . "')");



if ($resultado) {
    $messages[] = "Su registro ha sido exitoso.";
    correosoldevi($id_patrocinador, $name, $a_p, $a_m, $curp, $telefono, $correo, $imagen);// <--Hago el envio de correo
} else {
    $errors[] = "Lo sentimos, el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";
}

if (isset($errors)) {

?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <strong>Error!</strong>
        <?php
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
if (isset($messages)) {

?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
        <?php
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            echo $message;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Y esto es lo que me muestra como resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de envió correo (algunos datos que paso en la función no se ven porque quite las lineas de **$mail->Body** para que fuera mas pequeño el codigo para esta demostracion, pero si las ocupo)

```
    <?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require '../vendor/PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require '../vendor/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require '../vendor/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
function correosoldevi($id_patrocinador, $name, $a_p, $a_m, $curp, $telefono, $correo, $imagenes)
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = '';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = '';
    $mail->Password   = '';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->setFrom('', 'Nuevo Miembro Registrado');
    $mail->addAddress('');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Nuevo Miembro Registrado';
    
    foreach ($imagenes as $k => $v) {
        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['imagen']["tmp_name"][$k],$_FILES['imagen']["name"][$k]);
    }
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Error al enviar mensaje: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {

      echo "Mensaje Enviado";
    }
}
```

Comment: En la funcion correosoldevi, en la linea 3, has probado a poner $mail->SMTPDebug = 0 en vez de 1?

Comment: @IbaiA. Era eso gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Se que vengo 1 año y medio tarde, pero la solución era simple.

Me acaba de pasar igual y me di cuenta que tenia activa esto:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

Y lo puse de esta forma:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

Con esto se desactivó el debug del envio.

Lo dejo para quien este teniendo el mismo problema!